# How to get an ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer + WMSTLayer based on same service to align?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wmts

The image below can be obtained by adding WorldTimeZone layers to the JSAPI map:

```
wmtsLayer = new esri.layers.WMTSLayer("http://servicesbeta4.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldTimeZones/MapServer/WMTS", options);
tiledLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://servicesbeta4.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldTimeZones/MapServer", { opacity: 0.5});
```

I believe this issue is that the WMTS scale values are based on 0.28mm/pixel instead of 96 DPI.

[image: EsriWmtsAlignmentIssue.png]

**Is there a way to make these two layers align correctly?**

Because a proxy is required I cannot provide working source but I did paste my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F2p76/1/).

Comment: I've updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/F2p76/3) to use sampleserver6 and the tileMatrixSet to "GoogleMapsCompatible" and got proper alignment.  I guess the issue I keep running into is differences in resolution/scale.  In this case you cannot mix tiles with differing DPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree on that the two different layers can't be published on the same map. As they have two different device resolution assumptions(wmts one is based on 0.28mm/pixel while esri one is based on 96dpi), the map scale which is based on these assumptions can't be unified. But if you put them on the same map, they will show misalignment.

Answer (score 2):

By using the GoogleMapsCompatible tileMatrixSet the LODS calculated as expected (DPI=96) and I got the two layers to align with each other.

[image: GoogleMapsCompatible]

```
new esri.layers.WMTSLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldTimeZones/MapServer/WMTS", {
                        serviceMode: "RESTful",
                        layerInfo: new esri.layers.WMTSLayerInfo({
                            format: "png",
                            identifier: "WorldTimeZones",
                            tileMatrixSet: "GoogleMapsCompatible"
                        })
                    });
```